# Using Welcome to Google Maps API Premier in iPhone

Tags: iphone, google-maps, signature

I am working on a commercial application on iPhone that is using google map. I have Google map api premier client id and cryptographic key to use google map for some limited services like "directions".I generated the signature key using this code:
http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-samples/source/browse/trunk/urlsigning/urlsigner.m?spec=svn2498&r=2498

But still the WS claims "too many connections".

Is there any problem for using Google Maps API Premier in iPhone?

Please Help.

Comment: It sounds like you're an existing customer, I encourage you to contact the support team via http://support.google.com/enterprisehelp/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=142858&rd=1.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can learn more on the quota on Maps API web services for Business users, here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/faq#usage_limits

Most likely not related to the use of the API from iPhones.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest that you open a case with Maps API for Business Support Team (new name for Maps API Premier). You can do it under:
http://support.google.com/enterprisehelp/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=142858&rd=1
If you don't yet have access you can also submit a request using a form:
http://support.google.com/enterprisehelp/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=142246#request

Putting the error messages aside , it seems alarming that you want to use server side geocoding from an iPhone. The problem with this is that you won't be able to scale as your user base grows since your limits are set.
Instead you should try reading on client side geocoding. 
There is a really good article that explains how to make this decision:
https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat

"too many connections" does not sound like an error message you might be getting from Google Servers, but rather something to do with the platform. If you contact support they will be able to check that for you.

I hope that helps!